# Oracle find values in varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, split

Is there any chance to find an exact value in a varchar using oracle sql?

I need to find an exact value in a String (see output).

This is my sql output:

```
Rights (varchar)
-----
#1  ( ID IN ( 1560 , 1760 , 1860 , 20200 , 3530, 16000 ) ) 
#2  ( ID IN ( 1600 , 20000 , 100000 ) )
```

I want to filter for example String `1600` and `1660`.

In this case only `#2` should be shown.

I tried `and table1.rights like '%1600%'` which of course doesnt work because it shows me `#1` as well which is wrong.

I also found this about using split which I cant integrate

http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-using-oracle-sql/

Any ideas?

Comment: You could split your strings, but doesn't `like '% 1600 %'` work (with spaces)?

Comment: No need to split the string, `LIKE '% 1600 %'` will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also found this about using split which I cant integrate
>
> http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-using-oracle-sql/

Good to see someone following my blogs and articles :-)

No need to split the string, use **LIKE** in the following way which would only consider a space before/after `1600` and no other characters:

```
SQL> WITH DATA(str) AS(
  2  SELECT '#1  ( ID IN ( 1560 , 1760 , 1860 , 20200 , 3530, 16000 ) )' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '#2  ( ID IN ( 1600 , 20000 , 100000 ) )' FROM DUAL
  4  )
  5  SELECT * FROM DATA
  6  WHERE str LIKE '% 1600 %';

STR
----------------------------------------------------------
#2  ( ID IN ( 1600 , 20000 , 100000 ) )

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping - your blog helped me a lot until now! I am a trainee and sadly nobody really helps me in company - sorry for asking silly questions sometimes! Keep the blog up! :)

Answer (score 1):

Find out if your Oracle database version supports  [REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) (is similar to LIKE).
Within you could write a regular expression, *something* like this,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (rights, ' (,|[:blank:]|\()16(00|60)(,|[:blank:]|\))');
```

Edit: I just improve the reg expression following the comments. **It will work even if some space is missing**. To search for any other values you only need to **change the value part in the middle** of the expression.

See the [regular expression syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix.htm#g693775) too

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis and outer square brackets in your pattern - so `'16(00|60)(,|[[:blank:]])'` would work. But it would also match, say, 11600, so you'd need to check what is before required value too.

Comment: The regular expression would be match simpler if oracle supported the word boundary operator \b. Also note that @Alex comment is correct and you need to do the boundary checks in the beginning of the expression.